# Running grunt just opens up a Notepad file instead of actually running the tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to create a basic Grunt file to execute some tasks.

Trouble is, when I execute `grunt` from within the directory of the project, a Notepad file opens, displaying the contents of `grunt.js` rather than actually running.

I've also tried naming the file `Gruntfile.js` but then I get a message

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:
```

and I've already installed `grunt-cli`.

The `grunt.js` and `Gruntfile.js` both look like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

    });
    grunt.registerTask('foo', 'A sample task that logs stuff.', function(arg1, arg2) {
        if (arguments.length === 0) {
            grunt.log.writeln(this.name + ", no args");
        } else {
            grunt.log.writeln(this.name + ", " + arg1 + " " + arg2);
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', []);
};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grunt, but it sounds like you may have a file association in Windows between whatever Grunt runs (is it a .js file?) and Notepad.

Comment: hmmm... well yes, Gruntfile is a `.js`. But when I run the `grunt` command, I'm not asking it to open a file, am I?

Comment: What do you see if you run `grunt --version` from the same location? If everything is installed correctly, it should spit out the installed `grunt` and `grunt-cli` version numbers...

Comment: @serg10 I see `grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing a `package.json` file. I simply never created one.

I resolved the problem by running

```
npm init
```

to generate it

Answer (score -1):

Even if grunt is installed globally, you also need to add it to your project - in your project directory, run:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Do not rename your task file (keeg `Gruntfile.js`), then running `grunt` should work fine.